# Gradient calculation via backprop in RNN

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, neural-networks

I'm trying to understand the gradient calculation via backprop in RNN but not able to follow at one step. The question is from [RNN](http://www.wildml.com/2015/10/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-3-backpropagation-through-time-and-vanishing-gradients/). 
In particular, I'm not able to follow from
    \begin{equation}
\frac{\partial E_3}{\partial W}= \frac{\partial E_3}{\partial \hat{y}_3}\frac{\partial \hat{y}_3}{\partial s_3}\frac{\partial s_3}{\partial W}
\end{equation}
to:
  \begin{equation}
\frac{\partial E_3}{\partial W}= \sum_{k=0}^{k=3} \frac{\partial E_3}{\partial \hat{y}_3}\frac{\partial \hat{y}_3}{\partial s_3}\frac{\partial s_3}{\partial s_k}\frac{\partial s_k}{\partial W}
\end{equation}
 I know chain rule but seems not that good.
Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: It's precisely chain rule.

Comment: Can you write some of the steps? Infact, I'm stuck at `$\frac{\partial s_3}{\partial W}$`. Now, how to expand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the backpropagation, the $\sum$ comes from the rule of the [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative). What you need to work on is 
$$\text{if}\quad g(t) = f(x(t),y(t)), \quad \text{then } \quad g'(t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} x'(t)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} y'(t)$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial s_3}{\partial s_k} =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if }\ \ k=3\\
0& \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
\sum^3_{k=0}\frac{\partial s_3}{\partial s_k}=1
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial E_3}{\partial W}\times 1=&\ \frac{\partial E_3}{\partial \hat{y}_3}\frac{\partial \hat{y}_3}{\partial s_3}\frac{\partial s_3}{\partial W}\times \sum^3_{k=0}\frac{\partial s_3}{\partial s_k} = \frac{\partial E_3}{\partial \hat{y}_3}\frac{\partial \hat{y}_3}{\partial s_3}\sum^3_{k=0}\frac{\partial s_3}{\partial s_k}\frac{\partial s_3}{\partial W}\\
=&\ \frac{\partial E_3}{\partial \hat{y}_3}\frac{\partial \hat{y}_3}{\partial s_3} \sum^3_{k=0} \frac{\partial s_3}{\partial s_k}\frac{\partial s_k}{\partial W}.
\end{align}
The last equality is actually trivial.

Comment: I got your point but not sure if this is `the way`  we do derivative? Because we don't know the final answer while calculating derivative.

Comment: $\frac{\partial s_3}{\partial s_2}=\frac{\partial 
\tanh \left(U x_{3}+W s_{2}\right) }{\partial s_2} \neq 0 $